# Array Elements inconsistently getting added in PHP with array += array

Tags: php, arrays

This might be a stupid question, but I am having trouble figuring out why this does not always work.  I initialize an array and then pass through a number of if statements that add another element to the array.  This seems to work most of the time, but sometimes an element does not get added even though the if statement is true.  Here is some code:

```
    $data = array ("command" => "/order/list", "account_id" => Config::get('DEFAULT_ACCOUNT_ID'));

    if (isset($post['data-mrn']) && $post['data-mrn'] != '' ) {
        $data += array("filter.patientid.equals" => $post['data-mrn']);
    }
    if (isset($post['data-name']) && $post['data-name'] != '' ) {
        $data += array("filter.patient_name.like" => '');
    }
    if (isset($post['data-accession']) && $post['data-accession'] != '' ) {
        $data += array("filter.accession_number.equals" =>$post['data-accession']);
    }

    if (isset($post['data-description']) && $post['data-description'] != '') {
        $data += array("filter.customfield-421250f4-ea28-42b2-b53d-06ba84f16d36.like" => 'xxx');
    }
    if (isset($post['data-modality']) && $post['data-modality'] != '' ) {
        $data += array("filter.customfield-421250f4-ea28-42b2-b53d-06ba84f16d36.like" => 'xxx');
    }

     if (isset($post['data-status']) && $post['data-status'] != '') {
        $data += array("filter.customfield-421250f4-ea28-42b2-b53d-06ba84f16d36.like" => 'xxx');
    }

    if (isset($post['data-date']) && $post['data-date'] != '' ) {

        $post['data-date'] = str_replace("-","",$post['data-date']);
        $data += array("filter.customfield-421250f4-ea28-42b2-b53d-06ba84f16d36.like" => 'xxx');
        print_r($data );

    }
```

If I pass in an mrn, an accession_number and a status and a date, I get:

Array ( 
[command] => /order/list [account_id] => xxx 
[filter.patientid.equals] => xxx 
[filter.accession_number.equals] => xxx 
[filter.customfield-421250f4-ea28-42b2-b53d-06ba84f16d36.like] => xxx 
)

and it leaves out the date, even though the print_r($data) is in the if statement for the date,
so the data += there is not adding that condition.  There are other combinations where it does not update the $data array even though it satisfies the if condition.  Just wondering if there is a better way to do that and why that is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the same key `filter.customfield-421250f4-ea28-42b2-b53d-06ba84f16d36.like` four times. Associative arrays must have unique keys. You can not do this:

```
$array = [
    'foo' => 'bar1',
    'foo' => 'bar2',
    'foo' => 'bar3',
];
```

If you have this:

```
$array = [
    'foo' => 'bar1',
];
```

And then try to merge an array containing an existing key,

```
$array += [
    'foo' => 'bar2',
];
```

PHP will throw away the duplicate item(s) because the key(s) already exists.

If you instead do this:

```
$array = [
    'foo' => 'bar1',
];
$array['foo'] = 'bar2';
```

Then PHP will overwrite the existing key with the new value, which isn't what you want either.

So, if you want to maintain all the values specified, you'll either need to use unique keys:

```
$array = [
    'foo1' => 'bar1',
    'foo2' => 'bar2',
    'foo3' => 'bar3',
];
```

Or use an indexed array:

```
$array = [
    'bar1',
    'bar2',
    'bar3',
];
```

Or maybe (fancy!) an indexed array inside an associative array:

```
$array = [
    'foo' => [
        'bar1',
        'bar2',
        'bar3',
    ],
];
```

Comment: Noticed that after I posted.  Unfortunately, this is for an API, and the recipient apparently allows for duplicate keys.  I'll have to figure out another way.  Thanks.

Comment: _"the recipient apparently allows for duplicate keys"_ I doubt that's the case -- how can the recipient possibly know what field you want if they're all named the same?